# Why does my app crash when it reaches the second element in a loop? (Selenium error)

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

I hope you can help me out with the following problem. I retrieve a list of IWebElements using the Selenium Webdriver. This list has 52 items at first. I want to loop through the list, but when I finish the first element in the list, the app crashes with the following error:

```
OpenQA.Selenium.StaleElementReferenceException: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document.
```

My code below:

```
List<IWebElement> examLinkElements = new List<IWebElement>(
                from sectionRow in _driver.FindElements(By.CssSelector("#main > article > div.c_2columns.columns.row")) 
                from examElement in sectionRow.FindElements(By.CssSelector("div.c_2column.columns > ul.seriekeuze > li > div > a")) 
                select examElement); 
            
foreach (var examLinkElement in examLinkElements) {
     //navigate to a different page and do some stuff
}
```

So from what I understand my examLinkElements has 52 items by using a linq statement. This is stored in the current scope (in examLinkElements). When I loop through those elements I navigate to a different page. So the element is indeed not attached to the current page. But I thought I saved the webelements locally, so I can loop through them. What am I doing wrong?

Hope someone is able to help me out.

Comment: Once you navigate to a new page, those elements become stale, they lose reference to the elements in the `DOM` before the navigation. If you want to navigate to all those links, I'd get the `href` of each as strings into a `List<T>`, then navigate to them using the `href`

Comment: @RyanWilson yea, thought something like that, but I only need the text and the href from each element. Should I save only those instead of the entire IWebElement?

Comment: That's what I would suggest and then use the `href` to navigate to the different links. Saving them as IWebElement won't work as I stated in my previous comment.